# Entity Framework + Team Foundation Server - edmx error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, tfs

When I try to update the existing edmx Model while connected to TFS i receive an error:
"XmlModels involved in this transasction are not editable".

What's even worse, is that when I try to generate a new model, Visual Studio just crashes out.

It happens only when I'm working online on a project, being connected to team foundation server.

So far the only solution I've found was to edit .edmx file using text editor...

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: The TFS project you are connected to, does it have Multiple Checkout disabled? If some other user (or yourself in another workspace) have the file locked for edit, you will probably get this error.

Comment: Multiple check-out is enabled. Whenever I try to add/update entity, output says: TF10121: The Path '...' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.  ModelLT.edmx has been automatically checked out for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/299134/vs2008-beta2-ado-net-entity-data-model-and-wpf-app-issues

Please make a copy of your edmx file before you attempt this action.!

> *For ADO.NET: Duplicate InheritanceConnectors and/or AssociationConnector seems to be the problem, so deleting everything in the edmx:Diagram tag except entitytypeshape fixes the problem when you save and open again.*

Other people indicate that closing and re-opening the solution or rebinding to the source control system completely could have a positive effect.